# Freezing Row 1 and Column A at the same time

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to "freeze" Row 1 and Column A simultaneously in Excel 2010.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why it is off topic?? Millions of people use MS excel and then most of us do need such feature which ideally should have been present. Can we be less bossy in marking such questions which add value and mind our own business?

Comment: @prash, this should belong to [superuser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: Some people here are very fussy and dogmatic about what is off topic. I think this is a very useful question.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Select cell B2 and click "Freeze Panes" this will freeze Row 1 and Column A.

For future reference, selecting Freeze Panes in Excel will freeze the rows above your selected cell and the columns to the left of your selected cell. For example, to freeze rows 1 and 2 and column A, you could select cell B3 and click Freeze Panes. You could also freeze columns A and B and row 1, by selecting cell C2 and clicking "Freeze Panes".

Visual Aid on Freeze Panes in Excel 2010 - 
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-freeze-panes-in-an-excel-2010-worksheet.html

Microsoft Reference Guide (More Complicated, but resourceful none the less) - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP010342542.aspx

Comment: I thought that it was only for one or the other, thanks :)

Comment: Good stuff. You just cleared up one of those questions in the back of my mind about how freeze panes works.  :)

Comment: I thought user should select A1 then freeze... Well user's mind always differ from what MS think...

Comment: Why is this so non-intuitive? This is one instance where Google sheets has a much better method.

Comment: Thanks for that. It's been 8 years since MS changed many features and added "ribbons" to Office and I still cannot get used to them.

Comment: Note: This doesn't work on Office for Mac, it only freezes Column A...
Fallback is to use splits.

Comment: I always gave up freezing both row and column thinking it's just either side... until today I made a worthwhile effort to search. Thanks!

Comment: Wanted to add an update column since this is still getting comments, this should work just fine on Office for Mac. But I suppose it depends on your version, I'm currently running Office v15 for Mac. Select the "View" tab and you'll have a "Freeze Panes" button that works as mentioned above. Select cel B2 and hit freeze panes and it would freeze both column A and row 1.