# Freezing panes to form a square?

Tags: excel, vba

Though this question I found how to freeze a pane so it freezes the first row and column.

[Freezing Row 1 and Column A at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915733/freezing-row-1-and-column-a-at-the-same-time)

I am looking to now know is there a way to freeze a "square" in excel? So cells surrounding A2:O12 are frozen? I know this is an odd request, but there is a reason for my madness. Which is I have users that find ways of doing the craziest things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, instead of using the freeze pane the way it was in the other link, I selected one square wider and longer than what was required and clicked on the freeze frame, it trapped the cells exactly the way I wanted it to.

In English, the row 13, and column P were selected, I clicked on freeze frame, and it worked.

Comment: Yes, I know, but when I posted I was in a rush, sorry :)